# Apache subdomain vhost + subfolders of several Magento 2 installs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix, mod-rewrite, magento2

Basically I want to have several stores under one subdomain as sub-folders. Like this:

- mysubdomain.website.com/magento2v1 - Magento 2 store #1
- mysubdomain.website.com/magento2v2 - Magento 2 store #2
- mysubdomain.website.com/magento2v3 - Magento 2 store #3

Steps that I did:

1. This subdomain will be run in a VPS server so first I needed to redirect the subdomain (mysubdomain.website.com, the one above) to another IP (the actual VPS server) using an A record.
2. Second I created a Vhost with the mysubdomain.website.com on that VPS server

This is the vhost on the VPS server, Apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    ServerName mysubdomain.website.com
    ServerAlias www.mysubdomain.website.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysubdomain
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And then in /var/www/mysubdomain I have:

- /var/www/mysubdomain/magentov1
- /var/www/mysubdomain/magentov2
- /var/www/mysubdomain/magentov3

Now the problem is, Magento 2 needs .htaccess redirects where it redirects /pub to the actual sub-folder. I can't seem to get these .htaccess to work. The htaccess is read but it seems like the folders go a little bit crazy.

- /var/www/mysubdomain/magentov1/.htaccess
- /var/www/mysubdomain/magentov2/.htaccess
- /var/www/mysubdomain/magentov3/.htaccess

Here's an example of this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/setup/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/update/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/
RewriteRule .* /pub/$0 [L]
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Can anybody help me get this .htaccess to work? I think it's related to the folder structure, the folder base, but I don't know how to do this and didn't found any other example.

Thank you very much!

Comment: A side note: you really should change that `ServerAdmin` setting in the configuration. The  `webmaster@localhost` does not help anyone ....

Answer (score 1):

The issue *most likely* is that you rewrite to the absolute path `/pub/` from within the configuration files  in the subfolders. How should that rewritten request be processed? After that rewriting step it appears to the *next* round of rewriting like a request to `https://sub.example.com/pub/.......`. None of your existing configuration files will get applied to that. And it most likely will lead to a http status 404. Which you should be able to see in your http server's error log file and also in your browser's console network tab.

Instead you should rewrite to the *relative* path `pub/`instead. Which would result in the next rewriting step getting applied to the request to `https://sub.example.com/magentov2/pub/.......`. Which would again get (correctly) served from within that subfolder.

In general you should try to keep global rewriting rules in a common place instead of doubling them in various parallel configuration files. Even better than a common distributed configuration file (".htaccess") in the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder would be to implement such rule in the actual central configuration file. That is faster, more robust, more secure and easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Any examples on how to do that? I've tried


RewriteRule .* /magentov2/pub/$0 [L]

But this still doesn't work perfectly. I must be missing something.

Comment: That would still be an absolut path, wouldn't it? I'd say `RewriteRule .* pub/$0 [L]` (based on your suggestion) or `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ pub/$1 [L]`. Whether that "works perfectly" is nothing I can answer, since I do not know your application logic nor the exact issue you are facing ...